# What are containers in cloud good for?

Tags: cloud

So I've been trying to figure out containers and their use in cloud-based services (AWS Azure etc.) and I don't really see anything why to use them. Either you can deploy your app (or service) on your virtual machine or you can do the same in container but it still just runs in some environment `Nx 1:1 VM to container`.

Second approach I thought of is that you have one powerful VM and on top of that you have the container manager that distributes the computing power to the containers `VM 1:N containers` - but what is the difference of the apps running on the VM without the containers? Woulden't the container management only steal your computing power by unnecessary overhead? Additionaly to that usualy the prices are lineary scaling (eg price for single unit stays the same with count) so to have 2 machines is the same as having one machine with two containers and double the performance.

If you could please provide some examples in any cloud service that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Containers are all about getting more density out of your hardware - that is, to be able to run your services more efficiently given the amount of resources you have (and therefore save some $).

The principal is based around the fact that containers are not the same as a VM, they don't have their own copy of the OS and so on, they're a much more condensed sandbox and managed by the containerisation technology on top, which controls what resources the container has access to.

This also lends itself to being able to scale more efficiently, and distribute more effectively (resilience), since if you design your system such that one container runs one type of service, the container management layer can coordinate how many instances of each service can be spun up or distributed at any one time.  Compare this to SOA architectures, which typically (not always) scale in tiers rather than services - ie. your web tier would be a set of VMs running your web server and services, app tier running multiple back end services, and so on.  With containers you don't need to make that distinction, and you may have 100s of independently scalable tiers.

Suits the cloud perfectly, where you only pay for what you consume - the more granular your application suite is, the more efficient it is to run, therefore the less resources you need to consume.

Container management technology then can also manage resilience, networking, distribution of workload, scale, etc etc...

For smaller applications or workloads that you may typically host on one or two vms (or maybe a Cloud service or VM Scale set if you want it to auto scale), using containers could cost more - typically you would want a minimum of 3 Vms hosting your containers to provide resilience via distribution of hardware, and some of these resources would be consumed by the management of the containers.  So a more suitable use case is a larger system with many different service components, each of which may have varied demand over time.

Depending on the technology, usually the number of actual VMS may scale, say between 3 and 20, but you would usually have multiple containers per node - eg. 20 on each VM, so with 3 VMS you'd have the ability to host 3 x 20 = 60 instances of services, before having to scale up VMs.  You don't have to predetermine what *types* of services those 60 are.  So you may start with 3 VMs hosting just 3 services - a web front end, a calculation service and a data access service perhaps.  As demand grows, you may end up with 10 instances of the front end service, 35 of the calculation and 5 of the data access layer - using 10+35+5 = 50 of your 60 containers.

There is a good visual picture to describe the density of containers here:
[Linux Journal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/containers%E2%80%94not-virtual-machines%E2%80%94are-future-cloud)

Comment: So the "container management layer" spreads across several VMs and you can scale the VMs underneath it?

Comment: So this approach is mostly useful in cases when you have some service that can't really scale on its own (for example it is only single threaded). But when you have an app that is capable of consuming all resources (cores) of the VM you get the same result with spawning new VM right?

Comment: yes, a good example would be a service that consumes workload from a queue.  In itself it doesn't need to create threads, as each service instance would run on a new container instance

Comment: Thnak you very much!